# Clarify the [normalize] tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

Does the [normalize](/questions/tagged/normalize) tag mean `normalize.css`, does it mean normalizing text (`ó` -> `o`),  the `Normalizer::normalize` function in PHP or something else?

Maybe someone who has enough privileges could split it into smaller tags?

---

**NOTE:** This question was posted before the tag wiki was submitted.

---

### My proposal

We could have tags like:

- [normalize-css](/questions/tagged/normalize-css)
- [function-normalize](/questions/tagged/function-normalize)
- [database-normalization](/questions/tagged/database-normalization) (already there)
- [text-normalization](/questions/tagged/text-normalization)
- etc.

Retag the retaggable [normalize](/questions/tagged/normalize) questions to the appropriate tag.

And then...

[image: BURNINATE!!!]

## BURNINATE THE [normalize](/questions/tagged/normalize) TAG!!!

---

What do you think?

Comment: There is also vector normalization in math/graphic. And database normalization (which has a tag of its own).

Comment: Oh great, one of the few times I can remember when a tag wiki would actually serve its stated purpose -- [Rules 3 and 4](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/), "Concentrate on what a tag means to _your_ community" and "Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag" -- and there isn't one.

Comment: Someone submitted wiki for these. Don't know how to deal with it, though.

Comment: ive started [tag:normalize.css]

Comment: @DanielA.White it got deleted

Comment: seems like i am going to waste my bounty :(

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to see how the [normalize](/questions/tagged/normalize) could get a clarification, it related with so much usage depending on the subject at hand, but...

**What exactly is normalize:**

> to bring or make into the normal state
>
> to bring into conformity with a standard

So, as to normalize the [normalize](/questions/tagged/normalize), one could have it being used for the purpose of the true meaning of the word, the normalization of something.

Any language-specific topic requiring a "normalize" would have to be prefixed with something:

**e.g.,**

Database normalization -> [database-normalization](/questions/tagged/database-normalization) *(already in use)*

Function normalize() from language xpto -> [function-normalize](/questions/tagged/function-normalize)

---

### Propose for a tag wiki excerpt:

> Use this tag for questions where you're talking about bringing or returning something to a normal condition or state.

Comment: Exactly what I had in my mind. But maybe the normalize tag should be burninated