# Burninate [normalization] and [normalize] tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request

The [normalization](/questions/tagged/normalization) tag currently has 951 questions. It describes itself very vague as

> Normalization refers to transformations which aim to reduce variation of various types of data and thereby allow more consistent processing, searching, sorting, comparison, etc.

A minority of the question are correctly tagged with this tag but most other questions should be tagged with [database-normalization](/questions/tagged/database-normalization) instead.

There is another tag called [normalize](/questions/tagged/normalize) (84 Questions) and itself describes as

> This tag has **no single, established meaning at this time**. In practice, it is currently being used for a number of unrelated topics. They include normalizing text, vector normalization and normalize() functions in assorted languages. For database normalization, please use [database-normalization].

How about burninating both tags?

([Related Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141122/clarify-the-normalize-tag))

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can burninate those tags until you go through them all and retag them, which will take a little bit of work.  We also would need to create some replacement tags like [vector-normalization](/questions/tagged/vector-normalization) and [normalize-functions](/questions/tagged/normalize-functions) (just suggestions).